# Memory layout of C++ vector of structs

Tags: c++, memory, vector, struct

Let's say I have a struct

```
struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};
Point p = {1,2,3};
```

I understand that in memory it is organized contiguously as

```
p = | 1 | 2 | 3 |
```

If I have a `std::vector` of `Point` structs, does the `data()` function return the array contiguously too? Or is there extra "stuff" thrown in as well? For example

```
Point p1 = {1,2,3};
Point p2 = {4,5,6};
Point p3 = {7,8,9};
std::vector<Point> points;
points.push_back(p1);
points.push_back(p2);
points.push_back(p3);
```

Would calling `points.data()` return the pointer to an array that looks like:

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8| 9 |
 ^ptr
```

Furthermore, if the struct were more slightly more complex, containing a vector, let's say

```
MultiDimPoint
{
    std::vector<int> values;
}
```

would a `vector` of these `MultiDimPoint`s also be contiguous? That is, would

```
MultiDimPoint mdp1;
mdp1.values = std::vector<int>(0,1,2,3);

MultiDimPoint mdp2;
mdp2.values = std::vector<int>(4,5,6,7,8,9);

std::vector<MultiDimPoint> mdp_vec;
mdp_vec.pushback(mdp1);
mdp_vec.pushback(mdp2);
```

give

```
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8| 9 |
 ^ptr
```

when `mdp_vec.data()` was called?

Comment: The memory layout is no different than an array of such structs (because internally that's what it is). Access to the internal array is available through the `data()` member function which returns a raw pointer to the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ standard leaves it up to each C++ implementation to define and use any padding for structures, that the particular implementation needs.

It is possible that your C++ compiler will add some padding to this struct, for hardware-driven alignment purposes, which would result in some "gaps" between instances of this `struct` in a vector.

Having said that, you're unlikely to encounter this kind of padding on modern C++ implementations for classes that contain just plain `int`s. You can determine whether or not this is the case for your C++ implementation by observing what `sizeof` of this `struct` is, versus a `sizeof` of a single `int`.

But if your goal is to write portable code that should work properly on any C++ implementation, you should not make any kind of assumptions.

Now, when you have a vector as a member of another class, and a vector of those classes, each vector in each class member is completely independent of each other, and you have no guarantees that vectors in consecutive class members will end up being in one consecutive memory block. In fact, you're pretty much guaranteed that they won't be.

Answer (score 1):

It is required that `std::vector` pack the elements in a linear array. However, `sizeof(Point)` may not be three times the size of an `int`. It might be rounded up to a size convenient for your compiler. There are usually pragmas to control structure packing.

Each vector allocates its own memory, so in the case of `MultiDimPoint`, they most likely would not be contiguous. If they were, it would be a coincidence. Also, the C runtime heap management may put extra data before and/or after the buffer you requested.